# Can't use global variable within a function

Tags: javascript

So, I just created this simple function that multiplies two given numbers:

```
function multiply() {
    var firstNumber = document.getElementById('insert1').value;
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById('insert2').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
```

I tried declaring both variables outside the function, in a global scope, so I could reuse it in the next function, which will divide these numbers, this way making my code shorter. It doesn't work though.

Can anyone explain me why?

Thanks!

Comment: You should search for "parameters". Or just find a simple function tutorial.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Generally, global variables are frowned upon because they are a common source of bugs in code. I suggest you learn about how to pass parameters to a function and how to return a value.

Comment: Provide all the code needed to reproduce the issue. The code you currently show appears to only be a fragment of the code you talk about.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it works fine. (The code you provided doesn't actually have any global variables. You mention some other functions but don't provide code.)

```js
function multiply () {
  var firstNumber = document.getElementById('insert1').value;
  var secondNumber = document.getElementById('insert2').value;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
```

```html
<input id="insert1"><br>
<input id="insert2"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="multiply()">clicky</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use global var inside function, as long as you did not declare another one with the same name:

```
myVar =1;
function byTwo(){
    return myVar*2;
}
```

Comment: @Quroborus, edited, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstNumber;
var secondNumber;

function multiply() {

  firstNumber = document.getElementById('insert1').value;
  secondNumber = document.getElementById('insert2').value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  divideExample();
}


function divideExample() {

  //using globals variables
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = firstNumber / secondNumber;

}
```

```html
<input id="insert1"><br>
<input id="insert2"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="multiply()">click me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```